# Execution failed for task 'apCompileDebugWithJavac' error when building gradle in android studio

Tags: android-studio-2.0

I am a new to android developing. I have been trying to Build the Gradle in android studio but it always returns an error. I have not been able to run my app even a single type on my android device. Thus, need some help. This time, I am getting this error
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not open local class set analysis write cache (F:\ANDROID_PROGRAMS_BEGGINER.gradle\2.10\tasks_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localClassSetAnalysis).
>   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

I have tried the following steps , but still facing the same issue :-

- Invalidate Cache/Restart

  Delete .gradle folder in C://Users/User_Profile  directory

Here is my build.gradle file :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.justjava"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
}
```

My gradle .properties  file is quite simple . It has just the following one line :-

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

I have been using the latest android studio version
Looking for an answer. 
Thanks

UPDATE : Just now when I again deleted both .gradle folders, I am getting another error which is

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
```

> Unable to delete file: F:\ANDROID_PROGRAMS_BEGGINER\app\build\generated\source\r\androidTest\DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.html

Answer (score 6):

Try deleting your **.gradle** folder in project root. Got same error for me and tried clean build project but no effect. Then i found that the problem is with gradle files. So deleted the **.gradle** folder and got it running. Dont worry about deleting Android Studio will automatically generate deleted folders